# CSS add button on top of image on hover

Tags: css

I'm fairly new to CSS and I was wondering how I would place a button on top of an object when hovered. Before hovering, I have this:

```
input[name=uh]~a:before {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0;
    color:black;
    z-index: 1;
    border: solid 1px #5F99CF;
    border-right:none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-image: url(%%Black%%);
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 1s, height 1s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 66px;
}
```

And when I hover it, I want to have an image (on code below in "background-image property) on top that, and when clicked goes on a link.  However, I have no idea how to do that. I currently have this on :hover. Any help would be awesome, thanks!

```
input[name=uh]~a:hover:before {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border: solid 1px #5F99CF;
    border-right:none;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:15px;
    color:#999;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    background-image: url(%%Battlecats-Menu%%),url(%%subredditrulesbutton%%),url(%%editflairbutton%%),url(%%eventdatabutton%%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: 500px 300px, 500px 60px, 50px 60px ;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    content: "No more battle cats until you finish your homework!";
    background-color: #00ff00;
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    width: 500px;
    height: 280px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the simple css code that I have created for you. I have added hover to the parent element of both object and the button.

I hope this will help you :)

```css
.button{ display: none; }
.object-inner:hover > .button{ display: inline-block; }
```

```html
 <div class="object-inner">
   <a href="" class="button">Click</a>
   <div class="object">
     I'm an object!
   </div>
</div>
```